# DataAdapter.Fill syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataadapter

So,

Trying to write a very simple method to update a single column in a database.  I keep getting a runtime error of "Syntax Error" near the commented line below

```
public void SaveStatus(string id, string step)
    {
        // assuming that there is only one matching student ID
        connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        string command = "SELECT * FROM tblSubmissions WHERE Id = " + id;
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connect);

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblSubmissions");  // syntax error near here

        dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StatusID"] = step;

        dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblSubmissions");
        dataAdapter.Dispose();
        connect.Close();
        connect.Dispose();

    }
```

Hoping someone can point out the obvious problem I'm missing

Comment: Post the exact error. Runtime error != syntax error, so it's in the SQL. Post the CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: Debug and check what your `Id` variable is? You should be using a parameterised query rather than passing a string.

Comment: Error is:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'bba6323c0'

Comment: ID is varchar column?

Comment: Remove second parameter (`"tblSubmissions"`) of `Fill()` method and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should be `"SELECT * FROM tblSubmissions WHERE Id = 'id_value'` - you're missing the quotes around the `id` value.

Use a parametrised query instead of string concatenation to fix your problem and get rid of the SQL injection issue:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblSubmissions WHERE Id = @id" , connect);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = id;
```

Comment: Thanks Marek.  So, I have since realized that the data type in the table I'm saving this value to is a Guid, so even though you gave me the best possible answer to the question I asked, I'm a little stuck on that (since there isn't a SqlDbType.Guid)

Comment: @deadEddie I that case I think you need to use `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier`.